# Is it better to use asyncio.sleep(0) or asyncio.sleep(n) for checking value changes in Python?

Tags: python

So suppose I have some short code in Python that repeatedly checks on whether a value changes:

```py
while something != False:
    await asyncio.sleep(0)
```

My question is: if I want to have the smallest possible impact on the event loops performance: is it better to use asyncio.sleep(0) or set a high sleep value like asyncio.sleep(3)?

Knowing this would be very helpful because I seem to have this predicament many times for the software I am developing at the moment! Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Without knowing the full context of your current predicament it's hard to give a concrete answer.

Comment: Hello, metatoaster. I am looking more for a general guide-line of how to use asyncio.sleep in code where you have to rapidly loop / run some function and you want to use asyncio.sleep to avoid crippling the event loop as much as humanly possible. I am not sure if the best practice is to call the function with a zero delay or if it would be better to set a high sleep value.

Comment: Again it really depends if you care about having the co-routine execute every time it got a chance. If there are no other active co-routines [you will see CPU hit 100%](https://github.com/python/asyncio/issues/398) without fail, but otherwise it will try to run every time it gets a chance and you will need to benchmark your own impacts.  Better yet, it might be good to figure out if it's possible to attach an event that gets fired (to be logged or handled) whenever your target variable/value changes.

Comment: ^ Thanks a lot, this is really useful to know. I will mark this as solved.

Comment: We do not have "solved" markings here - this is **not a discussion forum**. It is possible (although I think this was a design mistake) to "accept" an answer posted in the answer section, but there is no reason to post an answer here - the question is not suitable as asked, because it does not have a clear, objective answer.